# Django - can I sotre and run code from database?

Tags: django

I build program, when in one part  I have some ranking, and I would like to give users option to customize it.

In my code I have a function that gets objects and returnes them packed with points and position in ranking (for now it calculates the arithmetic mean of some object's values).

My question is is it possible to give e.g. admin chance to write this function via admin panel and use it, so if he would like to one day use harmonic mean he could without changing source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could just store a string in the database and `exec()` it with suitable arguments...

However, you'll have to be careful – Python code can practically never be sandboxed perfectly. In the event that you accept any arbitrary Python code for this, and someone with nefarious intents gets to your admin panel to change the expression, they can do practically anything.

In other words, **don't use raw Python** for the code you store.